# Markov Chains: Do different transition probability matrices imply different stationary distributions?

Tags: markov-process

As in the title.

We know that irreducible Markov chains have a invariant distribution which is reached after enough steps (Reference: Billingsley's Probability and Measure, Theorem 8.6).

Question: If two irreducible Markov chains on the same underlying state space have different transition matrices, is it necessary that they have different stationary or invariant distributions?

Comment: In practice, it seems that the two chains may have different transition matrices because those matrices may use estimates of transition probabilities from different samples. Then, if stable over time, the underlying process may have one (population) stationary/invariant dist'n. However, if one estimated chain has a different matrix than another, the two estimated chains will necessarily have different stat/invar distn's.

Comment: If M is a transition matrix of an irreducible Markov chains, wiht the proporty that M^2 is also a transition matrix of an irreducible Markov chains, then should not both have the same stationary distribution ?